# How to dynamic call a filed name in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, show-hide, ssrs-2012

I have a row group contains 10 rows and getting it's data from a dataset.

I am using this expression to hide a single row using Row Visibility > Show or hide based in an expression.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!staticfieldname.Value),true,false)
```

Can I use something like this instead?

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!dynamicfieldname.Value),true,false)
```

[image: This shows the table]

I need to go to each row Row Visibility > Show or hide based in an expression.

So I have to write this for each

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!PermanentAddress1.Value),true,false)
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!PermanentAddress2.Value),true,false)
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!PermanentAddress3.Value),true,false)
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!PermanentAddress4.Value),true,false)
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!PermanentAddress5.Value),true,false)
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!PermanentAddressPostCode.Value),true,false)
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!PermanentAddressCountry.Value),true,false)
```

What I need is to have something like this

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(thisrow.Value),true,false)
```

for me at least to be able to copy and paste despite the field name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may want to use a valid expression like this:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!dynamicfieldname.Value) OR
ISNOTHING(Fields!thisfield.Value),true,false)
```

Only one `IIF` is required.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I know it's only one iif - I am just asking how to use this in a dynamic way 

What should I use instead of dynamicfieldname?

Comment: What do you mean by use in a dynamic way? Explain with examples.

Comment: I have a table with 1 row group contains 10 rows 

each row in the table has a mapped field as below

[FirstName]
[LastName]
[Address1]
[Address2]
[Country]
[PostCode]

Now some of these fields have empty data on the database and I am applying Row Visibility Expression for each row like this :
Row1
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!FirstName.Value),true,false)
Row2
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!LastName.Value),true,false)
Row3
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Address1.Value),true,false)

Which will lead to keep writing the field name

So I want to to replace FirstName.value to This.Value

Comment: Or if you guys have a better solution to tell the table to hide all rows if row is empty , so I don't go and do it for each row. @alejandro-zuleta